# How to tell someone that I got some information from a third person

Tags: word-choice

How do I tell that I got some information from a third person - is it correct to say

"I learnt from team ABC project live date is 10th August" or "I know from team ABC that project live date is 10th August"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'live date'?

Comment: When a project is complete and is made available to customers/public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**According to**](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/according-to) -

> used for saying where information or ideas have come from

So you'd say "According to team ABC, the project live date *will be* 10th August" (presuming it's in the future).  As long as they did tell you this, it puts the blame squarely on ABC if it doesn't happen. :)

Comment: :) yes this is exactly what I want to say. Just a doubt - this is in active voice if I'm not wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could try saying:

- > Team ABC informed me that the project will go live on the 10th of August.

If you want to stick with your original statements:

- > I learnt from team ABC that the project's live date is the 10th of August.
- > I know from team ABC that the project live date is 10th August.

Not sure if the project has a live date or there is a project live date? Hence, I would probably work on changing that to something like the date on which the project goes live.

Comment: Here I'm not certain that the project goes live; it is just an information I got from the team ABC and I want to leave a level of uncertainty in my tone and make other person understand that I'm not deciding it.